# How to apply Ubuntu font in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, fonts

How can I apply Ubuntu font to Windows 7? I need to apply font to each and every settings of the font - such as taskbar, Menu Bar etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See part 7 of [this](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/282-window-color-appearance-change.html) forum post on how to change the fonts used by Windows for the UI.

This assumes you've identified the font type of ubuntu, and installed the ttf file on Windows.
The font can be obtained from [here](http://font.ubuntu.com/).

Comment: Instead of just a link, can you add the relevant bits here?